# Bitmap image from android studio to jpeg in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

i am sending bitmap format from android studio and in code i am getting image in this format bitmap format, how do i convert it in to jpeg format and save it to my public folder.

```
$images = $request->input('expense_file'); //on echo (android.graphics.Bitmap@41c9d270)
 $binary  = base64_decode($images);
 file_put_contents(public_path().'/images/image.jpg', $binary);
```

Comment: Why is your server receiving `android.graphics.Bitmap@41c9d270`? It should be receiving a base64 encoded string, not this.

Comment: i am sending images in bitmap format from android

Comment: Hmmm... don't do that. What makes you think PHP  can decode android bitmaps? Just base64 encode your bitmaps before sending!